# How do I deploy a solution in Visual Studio 2013

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2013

I am a rookie at C# development and I am working my way through a book that uses Visual Studio. My problem is that though my application is building successfully, it isn't able to be deployed because of an error. The error says:

> Registration of App failed..... error 0x80070003 Cannot install or
>   update package..... because the splash screen image cannot be located.
>   Verify that the package as a splash screen image that can be used.

I don't understand why this is the case because the project generated it's own splash images(the default ones) In the Windows 8.1 solution it is the the assets folder and it's also in the windows phone solution.

Has anyone experience with this error?

Comment: In `package.appxmanifest`, under the Visual Assets tab, make sure the Splash Screen value is pointing to the correct path.

Comment: What is the correct path it should be pointing to?

Comment: Wherever the images are that you're talking about here: *"[...] because the project generated it's own splash images [...]"*

Comment: It's pointing to Assets/SplashScreen.png. In the solution manager, the spash Screen is in the Assets folder. The package.appxmanifest is in the Common folder and the Assets Folder is in the common folder.